# the rendering of the same snippet varies with different zoom, why is that, how do i fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm working a simple page, here is the code

```html
<div id="leftinfo"
  style="position:absolute;left:10px;bottom:10px;width:150px;height:280px;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);padding:5px;font-size:13px;">
  <b>The Forest Grotto</b><br>Level: 6<br><br>Mobs killed: 378<br>Money found: 1p 93g 49s 80c<br>Jade found:
  1,953<br>Gems found: 907<br>Frags found: 0<br>Dust found: 0<br>Rooms cleared: 25/35<br>Challenge Rooms cleared:
  1/1<br><br>Percentage done: 95.83%<br><br>Points so far: 378<br><br>Exit: 3,2
</div>
```

the rendering of the same snippet varies with different zoom.

this is what it looks like in chrome zoom 90%

[image]

zoom 100%

[image]

zoom 110%

[image]

why is that, how do i fix it

Comment: I don't have an explanation as to why zooming affects whether the content overflows or not. All I know is that this can be avoided by not declaring a height.